# Can't place UIImageView behind UITableView in storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, storyboard, xcode5

I can't seem to position a UIImageView behind a UITableView on my Table View Controller. I'm trying to do this within the storyboard designer. Moving a UIImageView onto the View Controller just stacks the imageview onto the tableview. In previous versions of XCode I had a window that allowed me to change the stack order of views within a view controller. Is this still possible?? I've tried dragging the views around in the jump bar and this doesn't work. So how do I accomplish this using XCode 5?

Thanks!

Comment: Click on the image view and drag it till the blue bar is on top of the tableview. that puts the image behind your table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use UIViewController for parent of UITableView!

[image: view]

**Or** if you want to set Background of tableView, can use this code

```
self.tableView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg"]];
```

Comment: Thank you. How did you get that tree view? I have searched around XCode and I cannot figure out how to enable that view. When I edit within the designer all I see is the "Jump Bar" thing.

Comment: for get tree view, expand left bottom menu on interface builder
[http://www.uppic.org/thumb-1605_52F3267D.jpg](http://www.uppic.org/thumb-1605_52F3267D.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

UITableView has a `backgroundView` property. You will need to set it in code.

In your example, you're probably using a UITableViewController in your storyboard. This means that the root view is a UITableView and you can't add a UIImageView as a subview to a UITableView and put it behind the superview. Doesn't make sense.

In a previous version that you've made, I suspect that you had a UIViewController with a UIView root view, which you added a UIImageView subview and a UITableView subview on top of that.

Answer (score 0):

Every UIViewController is associated with a UIView, i.e. [viewController view]. In the case of UITableView, [viewController view] is of type UITableView, so when you add subviews to it, you're adding to the UITableView, not a superview of type UIView as you seem to expect.

I would recommend using a UIViewController to control that view, adding subviews of types UIImageView and UITableView.